# Castle Activerecord error is “relation does not exist” on Postgresql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, castle-activerecord, npgsql

ActiveRecord mape:

```
[ActiveRecord("JobTitle",Schema="public")] 
public class JobTitle :ActiveRecordValidationBase<JobTitle>
{

    [PrimaryKey(Column = "Id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "Title", NotNull = true)]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

DB connection:

[image]

DB config:

```
 public class DbConfig
{

    public static void Configure()
    {

        var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PgConnection"].ConnectionString; 
        var source = ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Build(DatabaseType.PostgreSQL82,connectionString);

        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source, typeof(JobTitle)); 


    }


}
```

And init on app started:

[image]

Test for example the Table:

```
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public string Index()
    {
        var jobTitle= JobTitle.TryFind(1);

        return jobTitle.Title;
    }
```

Error getting on Active record:

[image]

Trace is :

[image]

I understand that the request is еrror.Because incorrectly sending to pg sql query.
And this simple query for my "JobTitle" table:

```
  select * from public.jobtitle => Castle Active Record
  select * from public."jobtitle" => Pg
```

How can I solve this casting problem?

Comment: You've already isolated the cause.If you can't fix the query generator, just use all lower case table names to work around it.

Comment: **Craig Ringer** - what's the difference small or large characters?,and my problem Castle ActiveRecord query to Pgsql sql casting , for exp:`public.jobtitle->public."jobtitle"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL identifiers are *case sensitive*; `"JobTitle"` isn't the same as `"jobtitle"`. However, unquoted identifiers are *case-folded* to lower case. Case folding is required by the SQL standard.

This means that if you create a table with:

```
CREATE TABLE "JobTitle" (...)
```

you must consistently refer to it as:

```
SELECT * FROM "JobTitle";
```

if you omit the quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM JobTitle;
```

PostgreSQL case-folds `JobTitle` to `jobtitle` and you'll get an error about the table `jobtitle` no existing.

Either quote consistently or use all lower case identifiers.

More in the [lexical structure section of the user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

Comment: ok right!,thx for answ :).My problem not now any, and pg sql syntax's using Castle ActiveRecord merging!

Comment: I have the logic to this class.Here:`[ActiveRecord("JobTitle",Schema="public")]`

Comment: @lelyor I'm really not sure what you're trying to say with those comments.

Comment: Very neatly explained. The simplest solution (IMHO) is not to use CamelCase identifiers for tables and columns in postgres, but to stick to underscore_separated_words instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue, but *ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();* solves my problem. I guess you have to put this line of code after initialization of ActiveRecordStarter.