# Error Relation does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am getting a `[error: relation "causes" does not exist]` error from my node app. The relation does exist, I'm not sure what the problem is.

I created the table with

```
CREATE TABLE causes (

cause_id bigint NOT NULL default nextval('causes_cause_id_seq'::regclass),
cause_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
goal integer,
sponsor varchar(30),
organization varchar(30),
submitter varchar(30),
address varchar(34),
balance numeric

);
```

This is the query that's giving the error:

```
client = pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done){
    if(err) console.log(err);

    client.query('INSERT INTO causes (cause_name, goal, organization, sponsor, submitter) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *', r, function(err, result){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please share some code snippets ?

Comment: I'd bet that you did a `create table "NameOfRelation"` but you're trying to do something like `select * from NameOfRelation`.

Comment: You should show the **real, unedited, exact error message** and SQL query if you want help; the PostgreSQL version is also useful.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull Updated answer after edit.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if any of you facing the similar situation like I did.

> Please make sure you are using correct user/password to the correct database host.

I found I connected to a wrong database :(

Comment: sounds stupid, but also correct in my case. LOL. I used an environment variable for DB URL and forgot to source the file before starting the server.

Comment: Legend! I had updated my `.env` file but not my `.env.local` file. Big mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Directly before your `client.query('INSERT...')` call, run the following to ensure that your relation is accessible on the current connection:

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables', function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

If you don't see your `causes` relation among the results, then either the relation doesn't exist, or it was created under a different user.

Comment: I don't see it. There are only two users, I've tried both of them.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull then it sounds like you're connected to the wrong host / wrong database.

Comment: Everything is spelled right. I'm using AWS does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a case folding issue. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330639/398670) and [the PostgreSQL documentation on SQL syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

**After edit**: Looks like it isn't a case folding issue. Check `search_path` (`SHOW search_path` or `SELECT current_setting('search_path')`) and compare it to the schema the table is in (`\dt+ tablename`) to make sure the table is on the client's path.

Also make sure you're connecting to the same database.

Comment: They both say public. The connection string I'm using for node-postgres is `'pg://myusername:mypassword@localhost/tzedakahbits';` Do I need to specify something so that it can connect to the database?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull Well, when you use `psql`, are you connecting to `localhost` and the database name `tzedakahbits` there too? Try explicitly specifying the port after localhost, making sure it's the same port used by `psql` (run `SHOW port` in `psql` to see the port of of the DB you're connected to). Sometimes people are running more than one copy of PostgreSQL and get confused.

Comment: I specified the port, it still says the relation does not exist

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull What about if you try to query it from within `psql`? `SELECT * FROM therelationname`?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, I have two databases, one where the table exists and the other where it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was querying newly created table `Example`. This was my code:

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');
const dbClient = new Client({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'postgres',
  password: 'test',
  port: 5432,
});
dbClient.connect();
dbClient.query('SELECT * from Example', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
    dbClient.end();
});
```

I double checked connection parameters and any possible typos. It turned out that in `pg` you need to wrap the table name in quotes:

```
dbClient.query('SELECT * from "Example"', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
    dbClient.end();
});
```

Comment: This is only if it contains capital letters i believe

Comment: When the table contains camelcase naming format, it needs to be wrapped with double quote. (but not the schema name). i.e ) client.query('select * from scmcore."CustomersStatistics" limit 10')

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting using a Postgres URL, specify the database explicitly in it. Sometimes if you don't, whatever lib you're using defaults to your username as the database, which may be the wrong one. I just had this happen to me. See [PostgreSQL Connection URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/postgresql-connection-url)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue but setting my schema name before table name :

```
SELECT * FROM public.mytable
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 2 things

- `public` keyword
- Quote `"`

NOT:

```
SELECT * FROM public.SampleTable
SELECT * FROM SampleTable
```

SHOULD:

```
SELECT * FROM public."SampleTable"
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error when trying to create a table with user input for table name and then insert into database.

The solution I found was to create the create table and insert into as two separate functions, call the functions back to back, but the second one with a delay.

Guiding code is below:

```
function createTable(){
// your create table query here
}

function pushData(){
// your insert into table query here
}

createTable()
setTimeout(postTable, 3000); // for 3 seconds, can make is less, I used 3 secs to be safe
```